# Java Threads (Beginner)

Tags: java

I'm having an issue dealing with my java code here.

I was sure I've used al recommandation I've founded online. But it still doesn't work.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.Map;

public class GradeCounterImpl implements GradeCounter {

    ConcurrentHashMap<String, GradeCount> save;

    public GradeCount[] count(String[] grades, int nThreads) {
        if (grades == null) {
            return new GradeCount[0];
        }
        if (grades.length == 0) {
            return new GradeCount[0];
        }

        save = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        class WorkUnit implements Runnable {
            final String[] positions;

            public WorkUnit(String[] i) {
                this.positions = i;
            }

            public void run() {
                for (String pos : positions)
                    if (pos != null) {
                        if (save.containsKey(pos)) {
                            save.get(pos).count++;
                        } else {
                            save.put(pos, new GradeCount(pos, 1));
                        }
                    }
            }
        }

        int divide = (grades.length / nThreads);
        ExecutorService exe = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);

        for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
            exe.execute(new WorkUnit(arrayBetween(i * divide, (i + 1) * divide, grades)));

        exe.shutdown();

        try {
            exe.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }

        Collection<GradeCount> c = save.values();
        return c.toArray(new GradeCount[c.size()]);
    }

    private String[] arrayBetween(int start, int end, String[] target) {
        String[] ans = new String[end - start];
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
            if (i < target.length)
                ans[i - start] = target[i];
        return ans;
    }
}


public class GradeCount implements Comparable<GradeCount> {
    public String grade;
    public int count;

    public GradeCount(final String grade, final int count) {
        this.grade = grade;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public int compareTo(final GradeCount other) {
        final int gradeCmp = this.grade.compareTo(other.grade);
        return gradeCmp == 0 ? Integer.compare(this.count, other.count) : gradeCmp;
    }
}
```

## What it's to do ?

The code must be counting every String appearing in the grades array and saving the results in the hashmap and then returning their values.

## What's the problem ?

The code isn't (as you can guest with the title) not working fine. It doesn't count well and I'm having huge difference between big arrays tests.

### Observations :

When I test with small arrays (0 - 50 values), the program run well

### Now : What should I do ?

Thanks you for reading all here and I hope you can help me.

Comment: what does GradeCounter do and look like?  have you considered a ThreadLocal?

Comment: I'll update GradeCounter

Comment: You should not copy the array, instead pass a `hi` and `low` to your `WorkUnit`s.

Comment: Is there any diference between using either the complete array and find out the given values or only intervall (with `high` and `low`) which are going to be used to access the array ?
Aren't the two of them going to access the array the same way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
                    if (save.containsKey(pos)) {
                        save.get(pos).count++;
                    } else {
                        save.put(pos, new GradeCount(pos, 1));
                    }
```

You have a `ConcurrentHashMap` but your GradeCounter is not synchornized, hence call to `count++` will not correct

I think your `GradeCount` look like `{grade, count}` so I suggest you to use `Map<String, AtomicInteger>` isntead

Comment: Okay. But yet I've already tried to use `syncronized` on the whole block but without success.

Comment: Because you're executing this block on different thread, each has its own lock so it does not work

Comment: Okay, I understand better. Thank you for your help !